# Unable to switch display output with Nvidia PRIME to intel

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, nvidia-prime

I'm using **Kubuntu 18.04** and I have an Nvidia graphics card with **driver 430** installed. I would like to use the Nvidia GPU for its Cuda only and not for the video output. After some search online, it appears that one way to do this is to use Nvidia PRIME.

Here are my issues switching from Nvidia display output to intel (my onboard graphics card):

1. I've seen articles and images of *Nvidia X Server Settings* with *PRIME Profiles* tab. I don't have that tab.
2. Some people pointed out that the same functionality could be achieved with commands like `sudo prime-select intel`. I've done that without any errors. And when I run `prime-select query`, it shows me `intel` afterward. But still, I could only get video output out of Nvidia HDMI (after reboot). And it was a very low-resolution output without the Nvidia driver loaded.

BTW, I've purged all the Nvidia packages and reinstalled them from scratch.

Can someone please help me switch the video output to my onboard graphics card?

Comment: Switch it in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks but could you please be more specific? In this solution, do I still need the `prime-select`? Or just the BIOS?

Comment: Prime-select is for laptops with hybrid graphics. It makes no sense to use it on a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

reference: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1043405/linux/ubuntu-18-04-headless_390-intel-igpu-after-prime-select-intel-lost-contact-to-geforce-1050ti/

1. You must `prime-select nvidia` to enable GPU. `prime-select intel` will disable GPU.
2. Create a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "intel"
    Driver         "modesetting"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

3. Modify `/etc/default/grub`, add `nogpumanager` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` parameter. Then execute `update-grub`.
4. Reboot

After rebooting, in `nvidia-smi` you will see only 7MiB memory are used.
Worked in Ubuntu 18.04 with GTX1060.

Comment: Thanks. I did almost the same with one small difference. I switched to iGPU in the BIOS. I also didn't do your step 3 and I'm not sure what does it do. But I'm getting a 2MB in my `nvidia-smi` and the monitor is now connected to the onboard graphic card.